# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion

I all of a sudden have this issue after the update to 5.3 today. After changing the sizes on all (thumbnail, medium, & large), my images are still being scaled down. The aspect ratio is the same but the quality is lacking and that's just unacceptable.

this was deleted by "fuxia". It is a legitimate concern and I was looking for assistance on the issue. Why would a mod delete this?

Comment: I've moved your Q here as this is where Q's about the site itself go

Answer (score 7):

You didn't leave a comment, you posted a comment as an answer.

Think of it as someone asking an important question, having everybody stare at you when you announce the answer, and declaring the solution is: "I too have this problem", it doesn't make much sense. So if you have a comment, leave it as a comment.

It may be that you don't have the ability to comment, at the time of writing, you only have 1 reputation. You need at least 20 to comment, which should be trivial to get. That doesn't mean you can ignore the conventions and ettiquettes

Since you ignored moderator action and posted it again, I've converted your answer into a comment:

[image]

So what should you do if you have a problem and somebody else has asked that question but there is no solution?

- Upvote the question so it gets more attention
- Comment on the question with any information you might have that could assist people trying to answer the question
- Don't post comments as solutions/answers
- Raise awareness of the question elsewhere, someone might be able to help but not know about the question
- Read the answers already posted ( in your specific case, Mayeenul Islams answer appears to be the solution )
- upvote any answers that worked for you
- If you feel you can provide a better solution, post it as an answer

#### The Danger

Stack Exchange has automated systems to catch spambots, and by posting an answer you opened yourself up to downvotes. A deleted answer with downvotes from a 1 rep user looks a lot like a spambot and not a human. Those automated systems might mistakenly flag your account thinking you're a bot and ban you by accident.